# How to change cert_fringerprint into Android App to use Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem when show the map into my Android App. 
When I authorised the credentials into Google Console the fingerprint are different

This is the Log when execute my App.

```
2021-2418/eureka.seguro E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see      https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
03-01 15:46:13.057    2021-2418/eureka.seguro E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: AIzaSyBr9prMCijg7eEVKl2QC7CzFd6ATmhs0SY
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 53:1B:06:C8:DC:3E:1D:B6:A5:FD:1B:8E:FF:B2:55:78:B9:AB:DD:64;eureka.seguro
```

The cert_fingerprint not mach with Google Console.

Why the app take a different finger_print? Could change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2017 Update**

I had a similar issue. If you have this problem make sure you review the response from the console. In my case the issue was with the manifest. The Google console doesn't have the v2 anymore as an option except for legacy projects. So in the manifest:

Change:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

To:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Authorization failure` message means that the key in your API console and the key declared in your project are not the same.

First check this. If they are the same, try generating another key and do it again. This happens sometimes for no apparent cause.